# how to use runnable in android

Tags: android, runnable

Hi, I'm newbie in Java Android development and I want to know how to use `Runnable` in Android. It doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is my source code:

**MainTest.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainTest extends Activity {

    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    private Discovery discovery = new Discovery(this); 
    private TextView textView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text);

        android.net.wifi.WifiManager wifi = (android.net.wifi.WifiManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylockthereturn");
        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        lock.acquire();

    }

    public void updateView () {
        String msg = discovery.getMsg();
        textView.setText(msg);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        discovery.stop();
        lock.release();
        super.onStop();
    }


}
```

**Discovery.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;

public class Discovery {


    private String type = "_ikunet._tcp.local.";
    private String msg="";
    private JmDNS jmdns = null;
    private ServiceListener listener = null;
    private MainTest maintest;
    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();

    public Discovery (MainTest maintest) {
        this.maintest = maintest;
        setUp();
    }

    private void setUp() {

        try {
            jmdns = JmDNS.create();
            jmdns.addServiceListener(type, listener = new ServiceListener() {

                public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                    msg = msg + ev.getInfo().getName()+ "\n";
                    update();
                }

                public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                }

                public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                    jmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), 1);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    private void update() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                maintest.updateView();
            }
        }, 1);
    }


    public void stop() {
        if (jmdns != null) {
            if (listener != null) {
                jmdns.removeServiceListener(type, listener);
                listener = null;
            }
            jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
            try {
                jmdns.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jmdns = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:fadeScrollbars="true"
              android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Hello World, Android Discovery" />
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The `serviceResolved` is executed from the `Discovery` class a while after the application starts and should update the `textview` (from `MainTest` class). But this does not happen. How do I fix this behaviour? I think it might be a `Runnable` problem.

Comment: Do you want to execute ur "serviceResolved" as background operation?

Comment: Just echoing what Ads said, it appears you are doing all work on the UI thread already, so no need to post back to the UI thread.  However, it looks like you intended to do background/multithread work

Comment: the serviceResolved is automatically executed as Background by Jmdns package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may skip using `Runnable` as it seems unnecessary in Discovery.java. For example:

```
private void update() {
    maintest.updateView();
}
```

However, in case you are using thread to gather search results then what you can do is to make use of `runOnUiThread` in your activity class (MainTest.java). For example:

```
public void updateView () {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String msg = discovery.getMsg();
            textView.setText(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
private void update() {
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            maintest.updateView();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

But I would recommend you this:

```
private void update() {
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                      maintest.updateView();
                 }
            });
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
    }
}.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the handler a bit differently.

To me the Handler should be created by the Activity and handed to your discovery class.  This is better because you avoid "leaking" the entire Activity.

In the activity you would have

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what) 
        {
            case UPDATE_PROGRESS:                   
                handleUpdateProgress();
                break;               
        }
    }   
};
```

Then, if you need to post back to the activity you can use something like:

```
handlerFromActivity.obtainMessage(UPDATE_PROGRESS).sendToTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works :)

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     /* ... */
     handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);
     }
});
```